# При работе с Bitmap возникает ошибка: "Недопустимый параметр"

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, drawbitmap

Есть метод CreateMergePhoto(), который склеивает две фотографии размером 1920х1080px и добавляет на них временную метку. Во время цикла на 235 фотографии, постоянно возникает ошибка:

```
  System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Сообщение = Недопустимый параметр.
  Источник = System.Drawing
  Трассировка стека:
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at TestMergeCSharp.Program.CreateMergePhoto() in D:\...\Program.cs:line 55
   at TestMergeCSharp.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\...\Program.cs:line 34
```

Первая строка ссылается на:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
```

Вторая, на вызов метода:

```
CreateMergePhoto();
```

Код программы:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Нажмите клавижу для запуска...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    while(CntMerge < 300)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Изображение: " + CntMerge);
        CreateMergePhoto();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Код метода:

```
private static void CreateMergePhoto()
{
    CheckImages();

    string img1 = PathToSave1;
    string img2 = PathToSave2;

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bm1 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img1, true);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bm2 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img2, true);

    int width  = bm1.Width > bm2.Width ? bm1.Width : bm2.Width;
    int height = bm1.Height + bm2.Height;

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
    bm.SetResolution(72, 72);

    string currTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, 0, 0, width, height);
    g.DrawImage(bm1, 0, 0, bm1.Width, bm1.Height);
    g.DrawImage(bm2, 0, bm1.Height, bm2.Width, bm2.Height);

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, height / 2, width, 56);
    g.DrawString(currTime, new Font("Arial", 52f), Brushes.White, 2, height / 2);

    bm.Save(PathToSave, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    bm.Dispose();
    bm1.Dispose();
    bm2.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Если вам в ошибке пишет "Недопустимый параметр", и ошибка указывает на `Bitmap(width, height);`, то логично, что `width` и/или `heigth` у вас имею не то, что надо, логично ведь, да? Ну а раз логично, то может стоит посмотреть в момент ошибки, через отладку, чтоб там всеж за значения такие вы передаете, и почему они не те, что требуются? Вы ведь сами видите, что код у вас вроде как работает, но на одной конкретной картинке он вдруг выдает ошибку, стоит изучить ее, какие у нее параметры, и так далее.

Comment: `Graphics` тоже нужно освобождать, поэтому добавьте `g.Dispose();`. / Ещё лучше использовать `using`: `using Bitmap ...`, `using Graphics ...` и т. п. При этом вызывать `Dispose` уже не нужно.

Comment: Кстати, `Font` тоже нужно диспозить. А так как он не меняется от вызова к вызову, то я бы создал шрифт за пределами цикла `while`.

Comment: Наверняка или width или height у вас 0. Ну и почитайте про `IDisposable` объекты.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Тестирую на одних и тех же картинках т.е. программа всегда объединяет два изображения, которые не изменяются никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему благодаря [комментарию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1536577/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-bitmap-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80?noredirect=1#comment2762431_1536577)

```
private static void CreateMergePhoto()
{
    CheckImages();

    string img1 = PathToSave1;
    string img2 = PathToSave2;

    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bm1 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img1, true))
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bm2 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img2, true))
        {
            int width = bm1.Width > bm2.Width ? bm1.Width : bm2.Width;
            int height = bm1.Height + bm2.Height;

            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height))
            {
                bm.SetResolution(72, 72);

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
                {
                    string currTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, 0, 0, width, height);
                    g.DrawImage(bm1, 0, 0, bm1.Width, bm1.Height);
                    g.DrawImage(bm2, 0, bm1.Height, bm2.Width, bm2.Height);
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, height / 2, width, 56);
                    g.DrawString(currTime, fontArial, Brushes.White, 2, height / 2);

                    bm.Save(PathToSave, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```